# Flex HTTPService.send() doens't trigger ResultEvent

Tags: apache-flex, flash, httpservice

Hello 
I'm trying to send a simple GET request using flex mx:HTTPService:

```
<mx:HTTPService 
 id="service"
 resultFormat="text"
 result="loadJSONDataToTree(event);" 
 method="GET"
 useProxy="false"
/>
```

Code that is supposed to send the request:

```
service.url = base_url + "workbench/pipeline/";
service.send();
```

Event handler:

```
private function loadJSONDataToTree(event: ResultEvent): void
{
    // just making sure the method is called
    var f_dp: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    f_dp.addItem("2");
    TreeView.dataProvider = f_dp;
}
```

It appears that the send() method is called but the event is never triggered and the request is not sent, because I don't see any requests in my server log. What could be the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hook up the `fault` event on your `HTTPService`.  If there is a failure of any kind, your `fault` event handler should get called:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#event:fault